# Joining objects causes some to be displaced

Tags: objects

I recently bought a house model, and after joining the objects that comprise the house, some objects are displaced and have their scales reset.
Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z42yz.jpg

Thanks!

edit: there were some objects "nested" within other objects. I'm new to blender so that's likely the wrong term
I individually selected each "nested" object and then joined the objects, but is there a way to go about doing that faster?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In your scene some objects are parented to others:

- That's why they are under their parent in the *Outliner* hierarchy
- An object that is parented will visually follow its parent transformations (location, rotation and scale) but it’s only visual, it will keep its own transformations unchanged. If you un parent an object, or parent it to another object, it will go back to its original transformations (unless you unparent with the *Clear and Keep Transformation* option), it’s probably what’s happening here.

It’s not clear what you’re currently doing but you could select all your objects and press <kbd>J</kbd> to join them all into one object, it won’t change them visually.